# Преобразовать объект в массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы, api, telegram-bot, объекты

Хотел бы поинтересоваться, как преобразовать объект, получаемый от АПИ Телеграмма. Ниже моя попытка:

```
        $Image = [];
        for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) { 
            $photo = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\Inline\QueryResult\Photo($i,'http://site.ru/telegram/image/'.$i.'.jpg', 'http://site.ru/telegram/thumbinals/1.jpg');
            (array) $photo;
            $Image = $photo[$i];
        }
        var_dump((array)$Image);
        $result = $bot->answerInlineQuery($qid, $Image, 100, false);
```

Comment: $result = (array) $result;

Comment: Вы преобразуете объект в массив и потом этот получившийся массив... собирается сборщиком мусора, поскольку вы его никуда не присвоили.

Comment: Максим Степанов, Это не подходит, потому что нужно преобразовывать до запроса. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы был массив типа: array($url1, $url2, $url3, ... ,$urlN).

Comment: rjhdby, не очень вас понял. Когда его тогда присваивать?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему.

```
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
        $photo[] = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\Inline\QueryResult\Photo($i,'http://site.ru/telegram/image/'.$i.'.jpg', 'http://site.ru/telegram/thumbinals/1.jpg');;
}
```